# SSH Tunnelling with Azure SQL Database (PAS service)

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssh-tunnel

We have Azure SQL database (PAS) and planning to disable public deny access,so that we can't access the database from out side the virtual network. In order to access the database we created jumpserver (linux machine).
Currently we are executing the sql queries from Linux Jumphost, howerver Dev team wanted to access the database using DBeaver tool (onpremise env), so I am trying to enable SSH Tunnelling between Onpremise env and Azure database (Through Jump Server)
So i used following command to for port forwarding
ssh -A -L 8000:test.database.windows.net:1433 -i jumpprivatekey jumpuser@publicIp

Then opened DBeaver tool and provided SQL credentials . I am getting following exeception

The TCP/IP connection to the host 127.0.0.1, port 43753 has failed. Error: 'The driver received an unexpected pre-login response. Verify the connection properties and check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. This driver can be used only with SQL Server 2005 or later.'. ClientConnectionId:8147d2a0-a0d7-42e0-a4d2-948a4c1338bb

Can you please let me know is it possbile to Tunnel the Azure SQL database from onpremise environemnt without any point to site VPN. Or what is the best approach to accessing the Azure SQL database

Comment: Was there some reason you didn't use `-L 1433:test.database.windows.net:1433`? If you've already got something else listening on localhost:1433 you could still use `-L 127.0.0.2:1433:test.database.windows.net:1433` because the entire 127.0.0.0/8 address range is available for loopback connections.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already try with this command (ssh -L 1433:test.database.windows.net:1433 userid@jumphostip -p port) and then connected to   DBeaver and provided database credentials. Still I am getting same error as above. Request you to provide some more info. Thanks

Comment: I'm using a similar setup to yours. I use DBeaver, but instead of setting up the tunnel outside of DBeaver, I use the SSH settings tab of the connection to tunnel through a host that has access to the DB in Azure. For this to work, I had to change the username from "user" to "user@dbhost" (dbhost in your example would be test.database.windows.net). This requires SQL Server Authentication. Perhaps you can use this trick in your scenario, too. HTH.